# How to add DKIM feature to the IIS 7.5 - Windows Server 2008 - DomainKeys Identified Mail

Tags: smtp, iis-7.5, dkim, smtp-auth

How to add DKIM feature to the IIS 7.5 - Windows Server 2008

DomainKeys Identified Mail

Comment: I see that you've asked this question on just about every conceivable website that could ever have anyone that works with IIS on it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is virtually no way to do this within IIS 7.5 (or any version of IIS for that matter). There may be a way to hack it if you write your own module, however that's not so much an IIS hack as it is your own hack that plugs into IIS.

There are third party tools that exist to perform this. For example, [EA DomainKeys/DKIM for IIS SMTP Service and Exchange Server](http://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/) from AdminSystem Software. However, for that price, I would suggest that you consider using a *real* [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) that will serve you much better in the short and long terms.

Consider some of the following products which are legit MTAs that will not need to be hacked or kludged to perform the functions of a real mail server:

- [IndigoStar](http://www.indigostar.com/indigomail.php) (Sendmail's Windows Port)
- [IceWarp](http://www.icewarp.com/)
- [Kerio Connect](http://www.kerio.com/connect)
- And more found in the following ServerFault threads:

  - [Email server for windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/79714/email-server-for-windows/)
  - [Zimbra Alternative Open source application](https://serverfault.com/questions/304380/zimbra-alternative-open-source-application/3)
  - [Looking for good Open Source email server](https://serverfault.com/questions/140871/looking-for-good-open-source-email-server/)

Comment: thanks for answer. are there any good companies which can provide me 300k mail for 300 usd  and below ? i also need to be able to use it in my C# application.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you will need to use open source tools for that. Look at IndigoStar for Windows or use A Linux server for your mail server with one of the many free and opensource email servers available such as exim or PostFix.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Having said that, it appears that the EA DomainKeys/DKIM for IIS SMTP product that I linked to in my answer is $300 USD and does not appear to have a restriction on how many users it can support. You can get a trial license from them and evaluate it.

Comment: @Wesley Any changes in this for 2018? For example for IIS 10.0?

Answer (score 0):

For Exchange you now also have the "DKIM Signing Agent for Microsoft Exchange Server"

https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange